# p-value for test regarding sample belonging to gaussian process

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, stationary-processes, gaussian

Suppose we know that $X$ is a stationary mean zero gaussian process with known parameters. Suppose an experiment provides me with a collection of samples $(t_i, x_i)$ for $i = 1, 2, . . . , N$. How could I compute a p-value for the hypothesis that the $x_i$ are the values of $X$ at the times $t_i$?.

I was thinking of using the cholesky decomposition of the covariance matrix $\Sigma=LL^T$ to get iid random variables, i.e., $Y=L^TX \sim N(0,I)$ but not too confident on how to proceed. How can I compute the p-value for the specified test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If knowing the parameters of $X$ means knowing the mean function $\mu(t)$ and the covariance kernel $k(t,t')$ then we can easily test for the values $(t_i,x_i)$. In fact, by consistency, we know that $X(t_i) = N(\mu(t_i), k(t_i,t_i))$ so we only have to test if $x_i$ comes form $N(\mu(t_i), k(t_i,t_i))$ for each $i = 1,...,N$.

Comment: I am slightly confused. $t_i$ I believe is the index and $x_i$ is the value, so what would $X(x_i)$ mean in your case? Also, my question was geared towards how to compute the p-value.

Comment: Edited, just thought it was the other way around

Comment: Thanks! But how would you test for that? it should be something regarding distances? distance of the potential realization to the center of the gaussian? This is why I thought rotating the pdf would be easier but am unsure how to proceed

Comment: I thought that you wanted to test if each $x_i$ came marginally from each normal given by the process. If you wanted to do it jointly i.e. all $x_i$'s come from the same process, then you have to test for the vector $[x_i, ...., x_n]^T$ coming from the multivariate normal $N(\mu(\mathbf{t}), K(\mathbf{t}))$ where $\mu(\mathbf{t}) = [\mu(t_1),...,\mu(t_n)]^T$ and $K(\mathbf{t})_{ij} = k(t_i,k_j)$. Is this last what you don't know how to do?

Comment: Yes, I am interested in the latter and unsure how to proceed

Comment: No prob. check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Multivariate_normal_distribution#Multivariate_normality_tests) out. I can put the link in the answer if you find it useful :). (observe that in this case, you'll have only one data point)

Comment: Would there be a way to make use of what I have above: breaking the gaussian's dependence and making use of integration in some fashion (integrating the pdf)? An emphasis on the p-value. As opposed to applying a statistical test. So building this up from scratch in a sense

Comment: Multivariate normality tests are not easy to construct; I'm aware that Mardia's test, for instance, uses an estimation of the sample covariance along with skewness and kurtosis. I'm not sure if there is a test using the Cholesky decomposition directly. I'd recommend you search for some tests and pick the one that convinces you the most. If you have any more questions, I'm glad to respond (if it's on my grip). Anyway, I think that the main issue of this question was already assessed.